# Tracking 2 points in 3D with a known distance?

Tags: tracking

I'm wondering, since I have a known distance in a recording (a stick's length) and a starting point (the base) is it posible to track the to points of the stick in 3D? I mean, since I know the origin and a distance between the two points, the second second one can only be in two Z positions. The system should be able to know X and Y in 3d space since the distance from tracking point x1,y1 to tracking point x2,y2 is known.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Yes. The transform values at each point in 3D space reflect the position of the origin. Use the Location and Rotation values to determine the location of the end points of your stick. Might be best to use python.